# Writing outside heap in mergesort

Tags: c, malloc, heap-memory, heap-corruption

I have been implementing vanilla version of a merge sort in C. In a sorting section itself, which is a separate function, I created a temporary array via `malloc`, like this:

```
int *tmp_arr = malloc(sizeof *tmp_arr * (end - strt));
```

For some reason I'm getting invalid reads and writes throughout all the temporary array while trying to fill it with elements after comparisons. `int tmp_arr[end - strt];` works fine.

Why am I writing outside of a heap (and what is happening if my current understanding is incorrect)?

Below are the functions where `malloc` is used, extract from valgrind output and exact mistake I am getting upon execution. I didn't forget to `free` stuff.

I got my initial array hardcoded as I wanted to write the stuff and bother with inputs afterwards.

This particular array `{ 8, 1, 10, 54, 2, 0, -3, 5, 70, 60, 11, 4 }` has the maximum length where I can have my program running, if longer - program crashes with the mistake described at the very end of the post. Valgrind output is always the same in principle, the longer the array is, the more read and write mistakes I am getting.

Program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void merge_sort(int *arr, int strt, int end);
void merge(int *arr, int strt, int mid, int end);

void print_arr(int *arr, int arr_len);

int main(void) {
  int arr[] = { 8, 1, 10, 54, 2, 0, -3, 5, 70, 60, 11, 4 };
  int arr_len = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]); 
  print_arr(arr, arr_len);
  merge_sort(arr, 0, arr_len - 1);
  print_arr(arr, arr_len);
}

void print_arr(int *arr, int arr_len) {
  for (int i = 0; i < arr_len; i++) {
    printf("%i ", arr[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
}

void merge_sort(int *arr, int strt, int end) {
  if (strt < end) {
    int mid = (end + strt) / 2;
    merge_sort(arr, strt, mid);
    merge_sort(arr, mid + 1, end);
    merge(arr, strt, mid, end); 
  }
}

void merge(int *arr, int strt, int mid, int end) {
  int *tmp_arr = malloc(sizeof *tmp_arr * (end - strt));
  //int tmp_arr[end - strt];
  int i = strt;
  int j = 0;
  int k = mid + 1;
  while ((i <= mid) && (k <= end)) {
    if (arr[i] < arr[k]) {
      tmp_arr[j] = arr[i];
      i++;
      j++;   
    }
    else {
      tmp_arr[j] = arr[k];
      k++;
      j++; 
    }
  }
  while(i <= mid) {
      tmp_arr[j] = arr[i];
      j++;
      i++;
  }
  while (k <= end) {
      tmp_arr[j] = arr[k];
      j++;
      k++;
  }
  for (int m = 0; m < j; m++) {
    arr[strt + m] = tmp_arr[m];
  }
  free(tmp_arr);
}
```

Extract from valgrind output with the array hardcoded above:

```
 valgrind ./main==355== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==355== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.==355== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright inf
o
==355== Command: ./main==355== 
8 1 10 54 2 0 -3 5 70 60 11 4 ==355== Invalid write of size 4
==355==    at 0x108A40: merge (in /home/runner/MiniatureEarnestSecurity/main)
==355==    by 0x108917: merge_sort (in /home/runner/MiniatureEarnestSecurity/main)
==355==    by 0x1088EB: merge_sort (in /home/runner/MiniatureEarnestSecurity/main)
==355==    by 0x1088EB: merge_sort (in /home/runner/MiniatureEarnestSecurity/main)
==355==    by 0x1088EB: merge_sort (in /home/runner/MiniatureEarnestSecurity/main)
==355==    by 0x108823: main (in /home/runner/MiniatureEarnestSecurity/ma
in)
==355==  Address 0x522d484 is 0 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd==355==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-
amd64-linux.so)==355==    by 0x108943: merge (in /home/runner/MiniatureEarnestSecurity/m
ain)
==355==    by 0x108917: merge_sort (in /home/runner/MiniatureEarnestSecur
ity/main)
==355==    by 0x1088EB: merge_sort (in /home/runner/MiniatureEarnestSecur
ity/main)
==355==    by 0x1088EB: merge_sort (in /home/runner/MiniatureEarnestSecur
ity/main)
==355==    by 0x1088EB: merge_sort (in /home/runner/MiniatureEarnestSecur
ity/main)
==355==    by 0x108823: main (in /home/runner/MiniatureEarnestSecurity/ma
in)
==355== 
==355== Invalid read of size 4
==355==    at 0x108AC8: merge (in /home/runner/MiniatureEarnestSecurity/m
ain)
==355==    by 0x108917: merge_sort (in /home/runner/MiniatureEarnestSecur
ity/main)
==355==    by 0x1088EB: merge_sort (in /home/runner/MiniatureEarnestSecurity/main)
==355==    by 0x1088EB: merge_sort (in /home/runner/MiniatureEarnestSecurity/main)
==355==    by 0x1088EB: merge_sort (in /home/runner/MiniatureEarnestSecurity/main)
==355==    by 0x108823: main (in /home/runner/MiniatureEarnestSecurity/main)
==355==  Address 0x522d484 is 0 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd
==355==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==355==    by 0x108943: merge (in /home/runner/MiniatureEarnestSecurity/main)
==355==    by 0x108917: merge_sort (in /home/runner/MiniatureEarnestSecurity/main)
==355==    by 0x1088EB: merge_sort (in /home/runner/MiniatureEarnestSecurity/main)
==355==    by 0x1088EB: merge_sort (in /home/runner/MiniatureEarnestSecurity/main)
==355==    by 0x1088EB: merge_sort (in /home/runner/MiniatureEarnestSecurity/main)
==355==    by 0x108823: main (in /home/runner/MiniatureEarnestSecurity/main)
==355== 
            
            //repeating till the end
            
        -3 0 1 2 4 5 8 10 11 54 60 70 
        ==355== 
        ==355== HEAP SUMMARY:
        ==355==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
        ==355==   total heap usage: 12 allocs, 12 frees, 1,156 bytes allocated
        ==355== 
        ==355== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
        ==355== 
        ==355== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
        ==355== ERROR SUMMARY: 22 errors from 16 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Mistake that I'm getting upon execution:

> main: malloc.c:2401: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == initial_top
> (av)  && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE &&
> prev_inus e (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) ==
> 0)' failed. exited, aborted

Comment: Please post a [mcve] in your question, not in an external link.

Comment: Ok, got it, done.

Comment: I guess i fixed the cause of closure, would be nice if it could be reopened.

Comment: @AntonTretyakov, it still does not follow MRE guidelines, namely the reproducilble part, post the test case(s) you used for the function. We can see the array but not the values you passed to the other parameters, my bet goes to corrupted memory by way of overflow or underflow of the buffer. Using the stack accesses out-of-bounds can be more forgiving than accessing unallocated memory, though still undefined behavior.

Comment: @anastaciu, ok, got it, added the whole text and a few words in array. 
I got my initial array hardcoded as i wanted to write the stuff and bother with inputs afterwards. 

This particular array `{ 8, 1, 10, 54, 2, 0, -3, 5, 70, 60, 11, 4 }` has the maximum length where i can have my program running, if longer - program crashes with the mistake described at the very end of the post. Valgrind output is always the same in principle, the longer the array is, the more read and write mistakes i m getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the length of the slice to sort is not `end - strt` but `end - strt + 1` as you are using the error prone convention to include the end element.

The allocation should be `int *tmp_arr = malloc(sizeof *tmp_arr * (end - strt + 1));`

The reason the code seems to work with the array declared locally with automatic storage is pure chance. You still have undefined behavior when storing data to `tmp_arr[end - strt]` but it just so happens that it does not seem to have any adverse side effect, whereas when you do so with the allocated object, you probably corrupt the internal data used by `malloc()` to keep track of allocated block, which gets detected by the allocation routines or a consistency check performed by valgrind.

It is very error prone to include the index to the last element in the slice. I wish this nonsense would no longer be taught in programming classes for any language with 0 based array indexes. It requires many confusing `+1`/`-1` adjustments in the code whereas using the index to the element after the last one allows for simpler code.

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void merge_sort(int *arr, int strt, int end);
void merge(int *arr, int strt, int mid, int end);
void print_arr(int *arr, int arr_len);

int main(void) {
  int arr[] = { 8, 1, 10, 54, 2, 0, -3, 5, 70, 60, 11, 4 };
  int arr_len = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]); 
  print_arr(arr, arr_len);
  merge_sort(arr, 0, arr_len);
  print_arr(arr, arr_len);
}

void print_arr(int *arr, int arr_len) {
  for (int i = 0; i < arr_len; i++) {
    printf("%i ", arr[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
}

void merge_sort(int *arr, int strt, int end) {
  if (end - strt > 1) {
    // avoid potential arithmetic overflow on start+end
    int mid = strt + (end - strt) / 2;
    merge_sort(arr, strt, mid);
    merge_sort(arr, mid, end);
    merge(arr, strt, mid, end); 
  }
}

void merge(int *arr, int strt, int mid, int end) {
  int *tmp_arr = malloc(sizeof(*tmp_arr) * (end - strt));
  //int tmp_arr[end - strt];
  int i = strt;
  int j = 0;
  int k = mid;
  while (i < mid && k < end) {
    if (arr[i] <= arr[k]) {
      tmp_arr[j++] = arr[i++];
    } else {
      tmp_arr[j++] = arr[k++];
    }
  }
  while (i < mid) {
      tmp_arr[j++] = arr[i++];
  }
  // copying the remaining elements from the right half is not needed as they
  // are already in the proper place
  //while (k < end) {
  //    tmp_arr[j++] = arr[k++];
  //}
  for (int m = 0; m < j; m++) {
    arr[strt + m] = tmp_arr[m];
  }
  free(tmp_arr);
}
```

Comment: You beat me to it.

Comment: I will shame myself for the rest of the week for such a miscalculation.Thank you for your help!

Comment: @AntonTretyakov: don't shame yourself, the convention is ill-conceived and everybody makes mistakes. Learning from one's errors is a powerful way to improve. Share your learnings and help others improve too.

Comment: @chqrlie, this later comment of yours, about the last element, is really enlightening. So now i can clearly see the question "why adding extra stuff for the sole purporse of adding extra stuff" that i should have asked in the very beggining. I deffinetelly have a quople of people to share this with, thanks once again!

Comment: @AntonTretyakov, well I think that given that today is thursday I think it's not enough, it should be the rest of the week and the next one :)

Comment: @anastaciu: today might well be Friday for Anton, or пятница to be precise, and by more than a few minutes :)

Comment: @anastaciu, considering the the other mistakes i ve done but found in this program that should be the whole two month exile, i guess :)

Comment: @AntonTretyakov: I fixed another potential problem: `(strt + end) / 2` could overflow on large arrays, ie with more than `INT_MAX / 2` elements, which is possible and would work with the `malloc()` approach. `mid` should be computed as `int mid = strt + (end - strt) / 2;`  It would also be better to use type `size_t` for all index variables.

Comment: @chqrlie, na zdorovie, tovarish, balalaika, babushka! I guess i m not that far away timewise from both anastaciu and you )

Comment: @chqrlie, wow, i shall remember that! So, you mean the numbers larger then long (or long long, if allowed)?

Comment: Type `int` usually has a smaller range than type `size_t`. On 64-bit systems, `int` is still 32-bit while `size_t` has 64-bit. Consider an array of 1.5 billion integers, easy to allocate on current systems, when you sort it, any slice in the upper third of this array will have `strt` and `end` greater than 2 billion, causing `strt + end` to cause an arithmetic overflow as it exceeds `INT_MAX` (`2147483647`). Signed arithmetic overflow is undefined in C and would likely produce a negative result in this particular case, which divided by 2 is still negative and `mid` would fall before `strt`.

Comment: @chqrlie, in this case i was sure that result of `strt + end` would be casted into larger type in case if `int` is not enough. Whould the type of the result be determined by the highest of the variables types? I mean, the type of `mid` cannot affect `strt + end` itself, right?

Comment: @AntonTretyakov: Unlike python where integer arithmetic is performed on bignums,  C does not do that: `strt + end` is performed on the larger of the types of `strt` and `end`, with some potentially counter-intuitive rules if the types have different signedness. in your case, both are `int` so the computation is performed in the `int` type and the behavior is undefined in case of overflow. The type of `mid` is irrelevant. The result will just be converted to the type of `mid` at assignment  time.

Comment: More about this: [Nearly All Binary Searches and Mergesorts are Broken](https://ai.googleblog.com/2006/06/extra-extra-read-all-about-it-nearly.html) and [The curious case of Binary Search — The famous bug that remained undetected for 20 years](https://thebittheories.com/the-curious-case-of-binary-search-the-famous-bug-that-remained-undetected-for-20-years-973e89fc212)

Comment: @chqrlie Dear Sir, i came here for a concrete answer for a concrete problem, but got a whole lecture - you have my deepest gratitude!